# Swagger not found in .NET 5.0

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a .NET 5.0 API project setup with API versioning and swagger. This is my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {

    // Set the swagger doc stub
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "API"
    });

    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
    string xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    string xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

and this is my `Configure` method:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I run the project locally, the `/swagger` endpoint returns a 404. However, navigating to `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` returns the swagger JSON document. I've seen similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811295/why-swagger-json-gets-not-found-error-when-hosted-as-an-application-under-a-webs), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68009438/requests-for-swagger-return-404-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407102/how-to-fix-swagger-json-not-found-in-net-core-2-2-app), but none of the solutions presented here fixed the problem, mainly because I'm not using IIS. I've also looked at Microsoft's official documentation, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), but I haven't noticed any differences. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you share us a hello world on github? I used swagger in netcore 3.1 without any problems

Comment: @JRichardsz I'm not sure what you're asking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section: hel to reproduce the error. If you reproduce the error in another minimal project, others could run your code and show you the error. Sometimes in the process of reproduce the error, you could find the error yourself. Swagger don't need database so is easy to configure. I'm shure that is a some settings or midleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by looking at [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1190). I'm not quite sure why, but removing the line `c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` from the `Configure` method fixed the issue.